# SpriteKit physics applyImpulse in direction

Tags: sprite-kit, physics

I am using the spriteKit-s physics engine. I have 2 objects on the screen, (say player and enemy). Now I am trying to use the applyImpulse method on enemy, which is supposed to pull it towards the player.

```
CGFloat radians = [Utilites pointPairToBearingDegrees:self.enemy.position 
                                          secondPoint:self.player.position];
CGVector vector = CGVectorMake(500*cosf(radians), 500*sinf(radians));
[self.enemy.physicsBody applyImpulse:vector];
```

However this applies force in wierd directions. Not consistent at all. Anyone have a clue why?

Ps. the radians are calculated correctly!!!

Thanks

Comment: "the radians are calculated correctly!!!" <-- I'd still rather see the pointPairToBearingDegrees:secondPoint: code to know for sure. ;)

Comment: Hmmm good chance that the vector is rotating in a different direction than the enemy.zRotation property, and perhaps even offset. In SK positive zRotation values indicating counterclockwise rotation.

Comment: + (CGFloat) pointPairToBearingDegrees:(CGPoint)startingPoint secondPoint:(CGPoint) endingPoint
{
    CGPoint originPoint = CGPointMake(endingPoint.x - startingPoint.x, endingPoint.y - startingPoint.y); // get origin point to origin by subtracting end from start
    float bearingRadians = atan2f(originPoint.y, originPoint.x); // get bearing in radians
    float bearingDegrees = bearingRadians * (180.0 / M_PI); // convert to degrees
    bearingDegrees = (bearingDegrees > 0.0 ? bearingDegrees : (360.0 + bearingDegrees)); // correct discontinuity
    return bearingDegrees;
}

Comment: I can't get the code into a code block... I inserted 4 spaces before the first line, with no luck...

Comment: Instead of placing new code in a comment, you should click on "edit" below your original question and add it to your question. Also, your function is converting a vector to an angle and later you are converting that angle back to a vector via sin/cos. 1) those functions require an angle in radians, so you shouldn't convert the angle into degrees, 2) you don't need the processing overhead of the trig functions when you already have a vector pointing from the enemy to the player (see my answer below), and 3) there is no need to "correct discontinuity."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
CGFloat dx = self.player.position.x - self.enemy.position.x;
CGFloat dy = self.player.position.y - self.enemy.position.y;

CGFloat mag = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);

CGVector vector = CGVectorMake(dx/mag*kImpulseScale, dy/mag*kImpulseScale);
[self.enemy.physicsBody applyImpulse:vector];
```

Comment: Id vote up, but I don't have enough reputation. This is certainly also a way to do it

Comment: what is "kImpuleScale" and where do you find it?

Comment: @silverSuns kImpulseScale is a constant value that you determine by trial and error. For example, #define kImpulseScale 0.25

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer. Is there any way to determine the scale of the impulse per screen size lets say?

Comment: @roimulia I suggest you pick a device and determine a kImpulseScale that works well with that device and then find scaling factors for other devices using the differences in screen sizes. For example, if you start with an iPhone 6 (width = 667) and want to compute the scale for a 6+ (width = 736), the scale would be 736/677 = 1.08715. Multiply this value by the kImpulseScale.